# MongoDB filter if all keys exists as fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I would like to filter documents where all keys (present in a list format) exist as fields. I could query multiple times with field as one of the keys one after the other

```
{ field: { $exists: <boolean> } }
```

but this does not seem to be particularly efficient. I am also concerned about the speed. Will it essentially be a linear search even if a few of the keys are indexed.

Also, is there a simple syntax for querying if any of the keys exist as a field?

*Edit:*

As an example, let's say `keys = ['key1','key2','key3']`.
Now, I would like to filter all those documents that contain 'key1', 'key2' and 'key3' as fields.

Comment: You might need to specify your actual query example for your intention to be clear. You Seem to be asking for all fields of specified keys to be present within all members of an array. Is this your question? Better if you edit it to show exactly what you mean. A true and false case helps people understand.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for pointing it out. See the updated question. Please comment here if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really mean here is the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```js
db.collection.find({ "keys": { "$all": ["key1","key2","key3"] } });
```

Which finds documents that would contain "all" of the elements in an array such as "keys".

The [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator you point to is actually intended to see if a given key value is actually present in a document like:

```js
{ "key": "something" }
```

So [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in the context would be:

```js
db.collection.find({ "key": { "$exists": true } })
```

Meaning that that field was actually present.

So if you want to match the "keys" of a document being present like so:

```js
{
    "key1": "",
    "key2": "",
    "key3": ""
}
```

Then you would list all of them in your query like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "key1": { "$exists": true },
    "key2": { "$exists": true }, 
    "key3": { "$exists": true }
})
```

That is just the way things work.

Comment: Thanks very much! Also, do you have any idea of how fast the query will be? I think it should make use of indexes (if some of the keys are indexed)? Also, if I use `$in`, it will filter a document if any of the keys is present. Right?

Comment: @Peeyush Adding an index to the "keys" field is a good idea. It is called a multi-key index when it is an array field. `$all` works as described in the documentation and is a shortcut for `$and` on the same field values. It makes very efficient usage of an index. Your answer acceptance would be welcome.

Comment: I am extremely sorry!! I interpreted your answer incorrectly :( . I am looking for `$exists` only except that I want to specify a list of keys rather than a single key!!

Comment: @Peeyush That is not how your question reads. Please specify a full document and what you expect. But I think the edit at the end of the answer explains it really.

Comment: What if I want to filter a document if any of 'key1', 'key2' or 'key3' exists. Any idea?

Comment: @Peeyush use the `$or` operator

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all keys exists, you can try:

```
db.collection.find(
    "$and": [
        {"key1": {"$exists": true}}, {"key2": {"exists": true}}
    ]
)
```

or you can also use "$or" to filter if any of key exist.

```
db.collection.find(
    "$or": [
        {"key1": {"$exists": true}}, {"key2": {"exists": true}}
    ]
)
```